# Using SSl in Azure Web App

Tags: azure, ssl, azure-web-app-service

I have an Web App on Windows azure which is shared Mode. The Web App is actually a Rest Service. So I want to make this secure and deploy an SSL certificate to it.
After researching on google and Stackoverflow, I figured out i cannot do so without scaling my web app to atleast Basic level. 
Is there a simpler tutorial which tells me how i can scale my app abd apply ssl certificate and what would it cost me ?

Answer (score 2):

Tushar, you can refer these articles:

Scaling an Azure Web App: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/web-sites-scale/

I am assuming you have already mapped a custom domain. In case you haven't, please refer my blogpost on how to do this: 
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaushal/archive/2013/07/06/windows-azure-web-sites-how-to-configure-a-custom-domain.aspx

Enable HTTPS for your Azure Web App:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/web-sites-configure-ssl-certificate/

For Pricing refer the following link: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/pricing/details/app-service/

You can also use the Azure Pricing Calculator to determine the costs: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/calculator/

Answer (score 1):

On the following page you can see that SSL is from

[Azure service plans](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/app-service/plans/)

You can make a cost calculation in the [Pricing Calculator](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/calculator/)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your need you shouldn't forget that any Web App is reachable with ssl support under its *.azurewebsites.net name.